# Check filename if correct file is downloaded using Protractor

Tags: selenium, protractor

I am trying to write a test case which downloads a file on click of a button. Now I am trying to read that file name and check if correct file is downloaded.
Below is the snippet I am using.

```
var filename = 'ABC.csv'
it('Verify that file is downloaded',function(){
PageObject.DownloadButton.click();
browser.driver.wait(function() {
    return fs.existsSync(filename);
}, 30000).then(function() {
    expect(fs.filename).toContain('ABC.csv');
});
```

I am doing something wrong as i am getting async timeout error. Can someone please help me find problem here?

I have added below code in my protractor.conf file.

```
prefs: {
    download: {
        prompt_for_download: false,
        default_directory: '/Downloads/',
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the jasmine default timeout interval value in the protractor settings? If yes, what is the value? Thanks.

Comment: Also, are you sure you are waiting for the downloaded file to appear in the right place?

Comment: This is what is there in my Protractor.conf file         ` prefs: {
            download: {
                prompt_for_download: false,
                default_directory: '/Downloads/',
            } `

Comment: I am using Mac so files are downloaded in Downloads folder.

Comment: allScriptsTimeout: 25000 in my Protractor Conf

Comment: They may be downloaded in `Downloads/`, but are you waiting for them to appear in `Downloads/`? (looks like that `fs.existsSync(filename)` waits for a file to appear in the directory from where you've executed protractor)

Comment: So how do i have protractor or above code look for something in Downloads/ ? I already specific default_directory as prefs in my protractor.conf file

Comment: I think i got it to work by specifying path in my protractor.conf. But when I am trying to read filename using `expect(fs.filename).toContain('ABC.csv');` it is throwing me error saying Expected undefined to contain ABC.csv. Any idea how to use this now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decided to move the ideas from the comments into an answer.

The most important thing to understand is that you need to make two things aligned together:

- the download directory where your file is going to be downloaded by your browser
- the directory you are watching/checking in the test itself

This has to be the same exact directory - and in your presented case, it is not - Chrome would automatically save a download into the `/Downloads/` directory, but you are checking the *current directory* with `fs.existsSync(filename)`. *Current directory* would be the place where you started your protractor tests from and it is not `/Downloads/`. This leads to your `browser.driver.wait()` to wait for more then the default jasmine timeout interval - hence, the timeout error.

Fix the directory path you are checking with `existsSync()`, something like:

```
var downloadDirectory = '/Downloads/';

browser.driver.wait(function() {
    return fs.existsSync(downloadDirectory + filename);
}, 30000).then(function() {
    expect(filename).toContain('ABC.csv');
});
```

Also, note that I've replaced `fs.filename` with `filename` in your jasmine expectation expression.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @alecxe. I achieved this by specifying default directory in my protractor conf.js and then using that default directory to check file.

```
prefs: {
    download: {
    prompt_for_download: false,
    default_directory: path.join(downloads),
    }
}
```

I also used a function to remove any file with a specified name in directory.

```
function rmDir (filename) {
    var filePath = 'downloads/' + filename;
    if (fs.exists(filePath)){
    fs.unlinkSync(filePath);
    }
};
```